Leave the lining paper or remove it with damage to the drywall?
I'm removing a lot of decades old wallpaper in preparation for painting over it. The wallpaper itself is easy to remove but the liner beneath it is giving me hell. I can't remove it without damaging the drywall surface. Sometimes it just flakes off with the liner. It might have been partially damaged before I even got started.
This got me wondering: is it better to keep going and seal the entire drywall before applying joint compound, or to just leave the liner and apply an oil-based primer?
In either case, at which point should I seal it; before or after skim coating, or both before and after?

If the lining is hard to come off, leave it on and paint over it.  You can even put textured paintable wallpaper on and then paint it.
Or, use steam to get it off. Your local hire store should have some wall paper removal tools.

I used a steamer.

I think the problem is the drywall facing—the paper/cardboard that is covering the gypsum.

The problem was the liner paper. I sealed it with Roman Rx35, and spackled it before priming it.

I'd probably go with scraping off the old liner which means some damage to the wallboard surface.  I'd then apply a texture to the wall - the kind that is actually thinned drywall mud compound applied with a texture sprayer.
No matter how you remove that wallpaper, you're going to have to apply a sealer undercoat, probably under the drywall texturing.

Possibly a skim coat too.
